# Card Widget won't update even though I wrap in a setState

Tags: flutter, dart

Below is a card widget which I have created. Why is it that when I press the button the variable ***cardDetailsCurrLevel*** even though it is inside the ***setState***, it won't get updated? Please help. Thanks!

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  getCardDetailsDetails(widget.cardDetailsIndex);

  return Padding(
    child: ClipRRect(
      child: Material(
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(
              width: 1.0,
            ),
          ),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(cardDetailsCurrLevel.toString()),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    cardDetailsCurrLevel = cardDetailsCurrLevel + 1;
                  });
                },
                child: const SizedBox(
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text(‘Add’),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

The card widget above being used in a ListView.
Edit: Added the Widget build.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

return Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    Expanded(
      child: ListView.separated(
        itemCount: fullCardDetailsList.length,
        key: UniqueKey(),
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          getCardDetailsDetails(fullCardDetailsList[index]);

          return Column(
          children: [
            CardDetailsCard(
              cardDetailsIndex: fullCardDetailsList[index],
            ),
          ],
          );
        },
        separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
          return const SizedBox(
            height: 0.0,
          );
        },
      ),
    ),
  ],
);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to put your card widget code inside build method

Comment: It is actually inside the build already. I just didn't manage to put in my question. I modified it now so that it can be seen.

Comment: is it in the same build method where you call the setstate ?

Comment: Yes, the setState is in the Card Widget too. But the 2 code I have shown is from 2 different class. The Card Widget class is just being called.

Comment: search for {ValueChanged} that's will solve your problem

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you meant. Do you want me to search for ValueChanged in google so that my problem will be solved?

Comment: yup you can see this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ubBy_btJtT0

Comment: Hey, this is so useful. Thanks for your help.